# Organize category articles from most recent to least in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table of posts in my database. In that table I have the article, the `ID` and the `Category_ID`. What I want to do is display every article where the `Category_ID = 1`, in the most recent to least order

Comment: I would start here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: Also, please refer to this guide with regard to asking questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you have only those fields in your database its impossible to know which was created first. You must have some sort of `created_at` field.

If you do have that field and forgot to mention, this is the `SQL` code I would use:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `Category_ID` = 1 ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
```

Substitute `created_at` by your time sensitive field and `posts` by your actual table name.

Comment: Ah yes I see, but then how would I then go on to display only the most recent one.

Comment: Ah, all I had to do was add 'LIMIT 1', thanks for the help though

Comment: Right. Also if the answer helped you click on the tick and accept it. Thanks